# diff and comm are not finding difference between two env files

Tags: shell, diff, comm

I have this env file

- 1.env contents:

  BARF_BAG=1

then another env file:

- 2.env contents:

  BARF_BAG=2

I run comm and diff on the files to see the difference:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

(
  set -e;

  first_env_file="$1"
  second_env_file="$2"

  if ! test -f "$first_env_file"; then
     echo 'first arg must be an env file';
     exit 1;
  fi

  if ! test -f "$second_env_file"; then
     echo 'second arg must be an env file';
     exit 1;
  fi

  echo -e '\n'
  echo -e 'displaying results from diff tool:'
  diff <(. "$first_env_file"; env | sort) <(. "$second_env_file"; env | sort) || true
  echo -e '\n'
  echo 'displaying results from comm tool:'
  comm -3 <(. "$first_env_file"; env | sort ) <(. "$second_env_file"; env | sort) || true
  echo 'finished diffing env files.'
)
```

and I get nothing, just:

```
displaying results from diff tool:


displaying results from comm tool:
finished diffing env files.
```

what gives?

Answer (score 3):

You do not seem to be running `diff` and `comm` on any files, you are comparing the output of the `env` command.

Since you are comparing `env`, the sourcing of the environment files is not doing what you expect as you would need to `export` the variables for them to show up in `env`.

Change your environment files as follows:

```
./1.env
export BARF_BAG=1
```

```
./2.env
export BARF_BAG=2
```

Now the `env` should be properly populated and your comparisons should output more what you were expecting.